# How to Remove this Black Layer

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, node-editor, objects

all!

I am new to Blender and 3D editing. I want to eventually 3D print this model of my Warcraft character, but I need to remove the black areas surrounding the shoulders and the sword. I made the replica of my character in WoW model viewer, and it didn't render the enchanted shoulders or sword properly, so I'm having to manually fix it. As you can sort of see in the picture, the rest of the shoulder pieces seem to be underneath the layer of black. When I tilt the character, I can see the rest of the shoulders underneath the black layer. How can I remove those black areas? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There could be more ways, but instead of guessing would be better to share your file  ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since these pieces are colored different on viewport check if the model has multiple materials or vertex groups, if you have either of these then it's very simple.

just go into edit mode, then in the materials properties select the material of the dark faces, and click "select"
[image]

this will select all faces with the assigned material.

another thing you can do is if these faces aren't merged to the mesh and just joined as the same object, you can select one of these faces then press L. this will select all linked faces that are part of the same mesh